# Prevent TODO state change from altering my window configuration?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** Which function does `org-mode` use to log a note with a
`TODO` state change?

#### Background

`org-mode` provides the option of adding a note when
[tracking `TODO` state changes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html).
That's great.

However, `org` is also cavalier about changing my window
configuration when it adds notes (i.e., it temporarily changes the
frame to a two-window layout), which is infuriating.

I've resolved the issue in a different setting when dealing with
[`capture`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) templates by
tracking down the offending function
(`org-capture-place-template`) and commenting out the offending
line that changes my window configuration.

#### Problem

I cannot find the analogous function for dealing with todo state
changes.  The `org` source code is sometimes rather baroque, and
I've gone through the source for `org-todo` without finding the
relevant call.  I suspect it's the same problem with a hard-coded
change to the window configuration that I need to comment out.

So: *what function does `org` use to log the NOTE with a `TODO`
state change?*

Comment: Looks like it adds `org-add-log-note` to `post-command-hook` within `org-add-log-setup` from `org-todo`.

Comment: @wasamasa: yes, that was definitely the one, thank you.  Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.  For what it's worth, commenting out the `(delete-other-windows)` line resolves the window-spamming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dug into Org a few times before, so how hard could this possibly be?  Well, the location is somewhat unusual.  If you follow along the sources of `org-todo`, you can see some comments about state changes to the `TODO`:

```
(when (and now-done-p org-log-done)
  ;; It is now done, and it was not done before
  (org-add-planning-info 'closed (org-current-effective-time))
  (if (and (not dolog) (eq 'note org-log-done))
      (org-add-log-setup 'done org-state this 'findpos 'note)))
```

According to its docstring, `org-add-log-setup` adds a helper function to `post-command-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'org-add-log-note 'append)
```

From this one can assume that `org-add-log-note` is the one we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for tracking it down.  I indeed missed it when scanning through the code.  In my half-hearted defense, it's buried pretty deeply around the function's 200th line with cryptic comments.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody stumbles on this in the search for preventing window config change when changing `TODO` state `(org-todo)`, I found it in `(org-fast-todo-selection)`.

As I struggled to change this, here is how I did it:

1. Find out where `(org-fast-todo-selection)` is

- `M-x helpful-callable` (or C-h f)
- Search for org-fast-todo-selection
- In the help find 'Defined in' in the Source Code section

2. Go to the definition and copy the code
3. Save the function to your init code (like in `~/.emacs`)
4. Rename it 
   I use `my/org-fast-todo-selection`
5. Alter the malicious code

- Comment out (delete-other-windows)
- `;;(delete-other-windows)`

6. Replace the original function
   `(advice-add 'org-fast-todo-selection :override #'my/org-fast-todo-selection)`

Now our version of `(org-fast-todo-selection)` without the window alteration.
Bliss.

Comment: (org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command) for when opening the agenda.